# Разделить строку и вернуть массив из объектов со значениями JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Нужна помощь в написании функции, которая принимает строку и разбивает ее на массив элементов по "/", удаляя пустые элементы.

Должен вернуться массив из объектов типа {id, token}.

Например, из строки:

```
http://google.com/hello/world
```

получить:

```
[ {"id":0,"token":"http:"}, {"id":1,"token":"google.com"}, {"id":2,"token":"hello"}, {"id":3,"token":"world"} ]
```

Подскажите как правильно?

Вот что пока у меня получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не делайте скриншот кода, вставляйте его текстом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно получить массив, каждый элемент которого соответствует элементу другого массива, можно воспользоваться методом [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Метод [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) может принимать в качестве аргумента регулярное выражение, это позволит обойтись без лишнего вызова `filter`.

В итоге код может быть следующим:

```js
const task = (str) => {
  return str.split(/[/]+/).map((rec, index) => ({
    "id": index,
    "token": rec
  }))
}
console.log(task('http://google.com/hello/world'))
```

Если могут приходить адреса оканчивающиеся на `/`, то проще воспользоваться методом [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) и получить все подстроки, не включающие `/`

Например:

```js
const task = (str) => {
  return str.match(/([^/]+)/g).map((rec, index) => ({
    "id": index,
    "token": rec
  }))
}
console.log(task('http://google.com/hello/world/'))
```

Comment: Бывают же и такие `http://google.com/hello/world/` - возьмется последняя пустая строка.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, обновил ответ. В принципе в задаче не указаны доп условия :)

Answer (score -1):

Для того что бы это реализовать можно воспользоваться следующими методами:

[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), что бы разделить строку по символу `/`;

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), что бы перебрать получившийся массив.

И задать условие, которое будет пропускать строки если они пустые.

```js
const string = "http://google.com/hello/world/"

let result = []

string.split("/").forEach((token, id) => {
  if (token !== "") {
    result.push({id, token})
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: _Данное решение быстрее варианта_ - есть какое-то сравнение?